# Xamarin Forms "App Not Installed" Error After Uninstall & Reinstall of APK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have built an APK of an Android app which I created with Xamarin Forms. The APK works perfectly, but if I uninstall it and reinstall it, I get an error message "App Not Installed" upon trying to reinstall the APK.

If I change the version number / version name and make a new APK, it can be reinstalled again successfully, but this means users can't simply uninstall / reinstall the same version of the app at will. How can I make it so it's possible to uninstall / reinstall the same APK successfully? Thank you.

Comment: Check out the logs with logcat, there could be some useful information

Comment: Have you created APK in debug mode or release mode?

Answer (score 2):

The solution from [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91725/app-not-installed-error) worked for me:

1. First change your build type to **Release** from debug.
2. Clean Solution
3. Rebuild Solution
4. Right click your android project and click on archive
5. After successful archive click on Distribute and click on Ad-hoc
6. Create keystore file
7. After finishing click on Open Distribution
8. Your apk file is ready.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found the solution [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91725/app-not-installed-error).
Basically, Play Protect will not enable you to reinstall, even if it prompts you again. Disabling Play Protect solved it for me.